# Is there any Way to replace the window.open for vaadin 14 to redirect to external url?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am looking for the substitution for the redirection as in safari and Firefox pop ups are blocked by default.

The things I have used is

1. open method of vaadin which indirectly uses the window.open
2. I know that the anchor Component can do the task but that will be costly for me as I have used the buttons and Image Component in the project so setting anchor will be hard for me.

Any suggestions will be great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening of the browser window needs to be connected to user action and happen on client side code, hence some JavaScript is needed. There is an [Browser Opener add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/browser-opener) for Vaadin 10+ which wraps this together.

Comment: Thanks @TatuLund It Worked perfectly fine for me..!!

Comment: I used Anchour in vaadin 14 that also worked perfect for me.